# Display all records from query on form

Tags: forms, ms-access, left-join

When I made a query, first only records with entries in all of the related tables where showing. I was able to change this behavior by changing the join properties (to a left join).

I want the same behavior for the form: all of the records should be accessible through the form. However, I don't find a way to change the join-type for forms.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query designer, double click the line that represents the join, it should give you a button called Join Type or something of the sort. That'll give you 3 options which are basically INNER, LEFT and RIGHT

To make the form have the same records showing, change the `RecordSource` in the forms properties to change the name of the record from the table to the query with the right join.

Comment: hm, I was actually talking about the *form* not the *query*. Or do I get your answer wrong? I'm not that familiar with access, sorry...

Comment: I thought this would solve the problem, but it caused another one: using the query as data source it is not possible anymore to enter data in the form. Is it possible to have the query as data source *and* enter data in the tables?

Comment: update: this problem was solved by changing the Recordset Type to Dynaset (Inconsistent updates) and making sure that there are no "group by" functions in the query (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-query-as-the-record-source-for-a-form-or-report-HA010096318.aspx)