# 1:0..1 relationship in an access form based on a query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database with several related tables. Some of the relations are 1:0..1.

I also have a query to display all records in table A and all related records in table B (if there are any). It looks like this (actual query is more difficult, but for the actual question this should be enough):

```
SELECT
    A.foo,
    A.bar,
    B.lorem,
    C.ipsum,
    C.dolor
FROM ((
    A
    LEFT JOIN
        B
        ON A.ID = B.[A: ID]
    )
    LEFT JOIN
        C
        ON A.ID = C.[A: ID]
    )

ORDER BY
    A.ID;
```

as far as I see, this query works as expected.

Further, I have a form to fill these tables with data.

Previously inserting data with the form worked well, but only some records (those with 1:1 relations between A and B and A and C) where displayed.

Then I changed the `RecordSource` to the query mentioned above (just as [@ashareef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2448686/ashareef) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448530/display-all-records-from-query-on-form)). Now all records get displayed (just as expected), but I cannot enter data in the fields B.lorem, B.ipsum and C.dolor anymore - when I do, I get an error

> Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value.

What can I do to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update back into that select statement. It doesn't know where to push the values back to.

For example if you don't get a match on table `B`, meaning `B.lorem` is NULL, but then you try and update lorem, it's not smart enough to create a brand new record in B with appropriate values.

I suggest you use a subform instead, or do some kind of VBA trick to create the record.

Answer (score 0):

Index or key cannot be zero or null - if you not inserted any value its default null. Check what is in table and what you try to insert.